Change of variable in functional Fokker-Planck equation
Starting from the following (steady-state) functional Fokker-Planck equation for the probability of a path $\{\phi(t)\}_{t=0}^T$
\begin{equation}
    0 = \frac{\delta}{\delta{\phi}} \left\{ \frac{\delta}{\delta {\phi}} P[{\phi}(t)] - \Big( - {\phi}(t)  P[{\phi}(t)] \Big) \right\}~,
\end{equation}
I would like to perform a change of variable $P[\phi(t)] \to P[\psi(t)]$, where
$$ \phi(t) = \phi(\partial_t^2 \psi(t), \partial_t \psi(t),\psi(t))~,$$
to obtain a corresponding FP equation of the form
\begin{equation}
0 = \frac{\delta}{\delta{\psi}} \left\{ F(\psi) \frac{\delta}{\delta {\psi}} P[{\psi}(t)] - \Big( - G(\psi)  P[{\psi}(t)] \Big) \right\}~.
\end{equation}
I suspect that a first step would be to replace $P[\phi] = P[\psi]\mathbb{J}[\psi]$ in the first equation, where $\mathbb{J} \equiv \mathcal{D}\psi/\mathcal{D}\phi$ is the functional Jacobian. However, I am not sure how to deal with the functional derivatives. References to material where this kind of manipulation is discussed are also very welcome!

Have you tried a kind of functional chain rule ?
